# How do I clear or remove unused files, as in hard drive directorys

Tags: directory

Is there a utility to defrag and clean hd's or recover crashed data. Like Nortons Disk Doctor, or Symantac's Disk Clinic?

Comment: Linux does not require defragmentation as the ext partition series(assuming you have one) undergoes very less fragmentation. I can get what you mean by crashed data.

Comment: Maybe he means core dump files? Or is referring to a filesystem check program, `fsck`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is also a good cleaning tool that I use myself, it's called Ubuntu Tweak, great tool. To install it, do:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppa
```

This will download the PPA repository, then you can go into Ubuntu Software Center and let Software Center do all the magic. Or you can do it all by command line (which is what I prefer) and use these commands after the PPA is loaded in your repository:

```
sudo apt-get update   
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak
```

Open the Dash and type Ubuntu Tweak then open Ubuntu Tweak with a click.

Comment: Three steps worked fine thanks Tweak looks like it works.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try `fslint`. Install it by running the following command in terminal: 
`sudo apt-get install fslint`.

It's a GUI version. Go through the options after installation. You can apply those options to all drives at a time or drive by drive as you wish, using `add` drive/folder option.

*More Info:*

FSlint is a toolkit to clean filesystem lint. It includes a GTK+ GUI as well as a command line interface and can be used to reclaim disk space. It has an interface for uninstalling packages, and it can find things like:

```
Duplicate files
Problematic filenames
Temporary files
Bad symlinks
Empty directories
Nonstripped binaries
```

http://fslint.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/FAQ

Comment: Installs ok. can't figure how to use it and can't get a manual for it. When running it asked questions I can't answer.

Answer (score 0):

Linux systems with `ext4` file system does not require de-fragmentation.
But if you want to delete unnecessary, temporary, caches files:

There is an application called [BleachBit](http://bleachbit.sourceforge.net/download/linux)

it has following features:

- Clear the memory and swap on Linux
- Delete broken shortcuts on Linux
- Delete the Firefox URL history without deleting the whole file—with
  optional shredding
- Delete Linux localizations: delete languages you don't use. More
  powerful than localepurge and available on more Linux distributions.
- Clean APT for Debian, Ubuntu, Kubuntu, Xubuntu, and Linux Mint
- Find widely-scattered junk such as Thumbs.db and .DS_Store files.
- Execute yum clean for CentOS, Fedora, and Red Hat to remove cached
  package data
- Delete Windows registry keys—often where MRU (most recently used)
  lists are stored
- Delete the OpenOffice.org recent documents list without deleting the
  whole Common.xcu file
- Overwrite free disk space to hide previously files
- Vacuum Firefox, Google Chrome, Liferea, Thunderbird, and Yum
  databases: shrink files without removing data to save space and
  improve speed
- Surgically remove private information from .ini and JSON
  configuration files and SQLite3 databases without deleting the whole
  file
- Overwrite data in SQLite3 before deleting it to prevent recovery
  (optional)

Comment: Thanks, it looks to complicated. I don't think I need all that stuff.

Comment: @DaveMan1950 in short it removes temporary files

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion of BleachBit.  But I still can't get a USB to be "live" boot with 15.04 16.04 17.04.  I need to run Norton's Disk Doctor and capture  lost files. You know I/O error's.  Symantec made one for Macintosh machines. Why doesn't Canonical have any idea what those are?